# Dynamic component with Dynamic fields in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, react-redux

I know there are a lot of other question-answers exists related to do a dynamic component in react.
But In our project, there is a different requirement.

### Our project structure is in this way :

- UI (different modules like user, manager, admin. These modules are
  separately implemented and fired-up on a different port) -
  implemented in React, Redux, Axios, etc.
- Nginx
- Back-End - implemented in Java as API
- Database

### We have requirements as per below:

Let's say there are components as per below in UI modules:

component1:

- field1
- field2
- field3

component2:

- field1
- field2

component3:

- field1
- field2
- field3
- field4

### We need to change these components as per customer needs (Customer can be #n. Not fixed).

### (We don't want to change the code every time. Meaning, when customer ask as per their layout, we do not want to customise code at that time. Can we develop any utility/design pattern/methodology, using which we can choose fields what to display/replace and everything else work as it is?)

### customer1 :

component1:

- field1
- field2
- cust_field3 (instead of field3)

totally new custom component2:

- cust_field1
- cust_field2

component3:

- field1
- field2
- cust_field3 (instead of field3)
- field5 (instead of field4)

### customer2 :

component1:

- cust_field1
- field2
- field3
- field4 (new in this component for this customer)

component2:

- field1
- field2
- field3 (new)

component3 not needed and completely removed

### Questions:

1. Is there anyway in React to do this kind of development?
2. Do I need to implement any utility to do this kind of component selection for the customer?
3. Do I need to use different tech stacks or third-party libraries with react? If any, please provide details on this.
4. Do I need to use dynamic rendering using JSON (storing in any database) for this kind of requirement?
5. Do I need to use any different design pattern or different approach? anything else?
6. How many efforts needed for this? is it really complex in react?

*Need support in this. I am stuck with this requirement.*

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of ways to achieve this in React.
The main question is if you can change the code of these components or not.

In case you can't:
you will have to create new components as per customer needs by applying a version of the famous "render highjacking".

In case you need this to work with composition (composition is preferred from inheritance for various reasons), you need to aply a Higher Order Component (HOC) that replaces the original render method.
Here is one link but if you search for the term you will find more options.
https://blog.callstack.io/sweet-render-hijacking-with-react-bb2b81d8d9be

In case you don't mind and you just need it to work fast go with extending the Component1 class, write a new render method and skip the methods that don't need enhancments.

e.g.

```
class Component1v1 extends Component1 {
  render() {
    return(
      {'My old and My new stuff'}
    );
  }
}
```

In case you can edit the existing components, you have a number of ways to achieve this.

Option1:
Conditional rendering

Not my cup of tea, but there are cases that it makes sense:
e.g.

```
class Component1 extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return(
      <input1/>
      <input2/>
      {customer2 && <input3_cust2/> : <input3/>}  
    );
  }
}
```

In general it does not make sense to have components that you need to edit for each and every of you customers, so I would go with a wrapper component that renders the other ones and enhances their abilities. From what I can gather it's better to leave most of the handling to the wrapper to be consistent.

Option2:
Wrapper that passes extra children

e.g.

```
class Component1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return(
        <div>
          <input1 onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
          <input2 onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
          {...this.props.children}
        </div>
      );
    }
}

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  handleChange(e) {
    return null;
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Component1 onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <input3 onChange={this.handleChange}/>
      </Component1>
    );
  }
}
```

Please keep in mind that this is pseudo-code, it won't work without fixes

Eitherway you can create wrappers for each or one wrapper for all depending on the occation. You pass as 'children' all the fields you need to be relevant to your customers.

As I mentioned before, it does not make much of a sence to have components that need modifications according to the client, you probably need to spend some time on grouping and splitting your view layer and your logic in a way that suits you. Meaning you need to redefine your Components.